# what is Remmina's "remoteFX" secret to running ANY sort of application remotely?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remmina

I am attempting to run an openGL application  from a remote pc.
Both pc's are on intranet (so GBit connection) and both are running ubuntu 13.04.

If I share the desktop of the pc running this openGL application , and connect to it with `Remmina's remoteFX` option, I can indeed -to my surprise- run this application.

Trying the same using `tightvnc` fails, because the application says it can not use some GL extensions..

Trying with `ssh -Y` also fails for the same reason.

So, what is the big picture (and the finer details) that make remoteFX possible?
Is it possible to enable something from command line, and enable this functionality for other X forwarding applications (like ssh -Y, nx, other vnc servers etc).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess after many months of search the best answer is to say that remmina incorporates virtualGL extentions.

I have not seen that anywhere stated explicitly, but I have only  seen opengl applications be runable when they are run through virtualGL.

Answer (score 2):

RemoteFX is a feature of RDP (Remote desktop) that enables "rich application" such as yours to run remotely. Remmina can do RDP, TightVNC doesn't.

This is why is working with one and not with the other.